# Cant use PowerManager's goToSleep APi in android

Tags: android, sleep, root

Hii  felas i was making  an app and i need to invoke the phone  going into screen-saver mode as i get a triger...
I  looked  around and  found out that **PowerManager.java** does provide such  an  API "**goToSleep**"

[API description here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29)

my problem now  is that  I need a special  permission to make this  work namely

"**android.Manifest.permission.DEVICE_POWER**"  this  permission being a level 2 permission just  declaring it in manifest  does not provide  me with the permission
so now i  have to  run the app in system  thread (have verified it works if i do so ) to get this permission successfully

**can anybody  provide me any tips or  any  other way  around as how i can make this  work  without rooting  my app** (is there some other way  to trigger the same behavior

Comment: My phone went for a swim in the bath (dont ask), so I want to develop a soft off button, so yeah, would be nice if this were possible. Tempted to bounty this.

Comment: well this  api  doesnt  actually "off"  your  phone it  just  moves to screen off state the Cpu  keeps  running it  only powers  down the display.

Comment: That is actually what I want. No need to power off, just switch of the screen so that it doesn't eat through my battery.

Comment: running the  app in  system  process with  system  shared  uid  seems  to be  the only way  out. (rooting  the app )   IF  SAVING  BATTERY IS THE CAUSE  FOR THIS ....SET  DISPLAY  TIME OUT TO VERY  SHORT TIME>>>UNLESS SOMEONE  FIGURE  HOW  WE CAN  DO THIS  WITHOUT  ROOTING.

Answer (score -1):

Under a certain brightnes value, the screen goes off so this should work:

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.flags |= LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
 
lp.screenBrightness = 0;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);